# MySQL — Error in your SQL syntax (WHERE IN UNION)

Tags: mysql, union

```
SELECT * 
FROM `SC_products` 
WHERE `productID` 
IN (
    (
        SELECT `productID` 
        FROM `SC_product_options_set` 
        LEFT JOIN `SC_products_opt_val_variants` ON `SC_product_options_set`.`variantID` = `SC_products_opt_val_variants`.`variantID` 
        WHERE `SC_products_opt_val_variants`.`optionID` = '14'
        GROUP BY `SC_product_options_set`.`productID` 
        ORDER BY `SC_products_opt_val_variants`.`sort_order` ASC 
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT `productID` 
        FROM `SC_product_options_values` 
        WHERE `SC_product_options_values`.`optionID` = '14'
        ORDER BY `SC_product_options_values`.`option_value_ru` ASC 
    )
)
GROUP BY `SC_products`.`productID` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

ERROR №1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL ( SELECT `productID` FROM `SC_product_options_values` WHERE `SC_produ' at line 7

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `sc_products` 
WHERE  `productid` IN (
                     SELECT `productid` 
                        FROM   `sc_product_options_set` 
                               LEFT JOIN `sc_products_opt_val_variants` 
                                 ON `sc_product_options_set`.`variantid` = 
                                    `sc_products_opt_val_variants`.`variantid` 
                        WHERE  `sc_products_opt_val_variants`.`optionid` = '14' 
                        GROUP  BY `sc_product_options_set`.`productid` 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT `productid` 
                        FROM   `sc_product_options_values` 
                        WHERE  `sc_product_options_values`.`optionid` = '14' 
                                            ) 
GROUP  BY `sc_products`.`productid` 
LIMIT  0, 30
```

P.S: You don't need an ORDER BY in your subquery becuase it is in a IN clause

Comment: Thanks, Cybernate. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you have to put the ORDER clause outside of the queries you're UNIONing together.  And if you do that, you'll need to make sure you select those columns in each of the to-be-UNIONed queries so you can order them once you've gotten your full recordset.

After that, you'll need to wrap those results in another SELECT layer so your IN comparison will work.

Comment: I try this (without GROUP and ORDER in UNION): SELECT * 
FROM `SC_products` 
WHERE `productID` 
IN (
(

SELECT `productID` 
FROM `SC_product_options_set` 
LEFT JOIN `SC_products_opt_val_variants` ON `SC_product_options_set`.`variantID` = `SC_products_opt_val_variants`.`variantID` 
WHERE `SC_products_opt_val_variants`.`optionID` = '14'
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT `productID` 
FROM `SC_product_options_values` 
WHERE `SC_product_options_values`.`optionID` = '14'
)
)
GROUP BY `SC_products`.`productID` 
LIMIT 0 , 30 But I still have the problem on the same line

Comment: What I usually do when I'm trying to debug these sorts of things is to run each of my inner queries independently to verify that their syntax and composition is correct.  Once I'm sure of each of my components, then any problems I have when putting them together are much easier to solve.  It looks like @Cybernate has you covered here, but in case you run into problems like this in the future, this debugging technique might save you some pain in the future.  =)

Comment: Kyle Humfeld, I tried to make a request for UNION block at first and there was no problems. Thanks for the advice.